# Wrong/AutoGenerated Provisioning Profile when Submitting Build to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am attempting to upload my iOS app build. After clicking submit from the Organizer-Archives window in Xcode, it seems to select the wrong Provisioning profile to submit. It is also not editable.

I have the correct iPhone Distribution signing identities, and App Store provisioning profile in both the project and target (under Build Settings).

I'm skeptical about submitting the app with this auto-selected Provisioning Profile (`"XC: Rajib.Tho"`) instead of "My Parse Push App Store Profile." Am I doing something wrong here? My app uses push notifications so I want to make sure the provisioning profile is set up correctly before submitting.

Screenshot here of what I see:

[image]

Comment: Go to XCode Preferences from the menu bar. And then click on Accounts tab in it where you have added the Apple account. Go to the view details and delete the auto created provisioning profile prefixed with XC: The XCode creates the profile automatically. Either you delete the provisioning profile that you created or the one you created. Both are same profiles. Yes this is weird that when you selected your own created provisioning profile then XCode should have picked that. But may be it is an Xcode bug. Try this and update us.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I tried what you suggested (deleting the provisioning profile they generated "XC:Rajib.Tho".  Unfortunately when I attempt to submit the build again it auto generates the same profile again, and forces me to submit it with this newly auto generated provisioning profile.  Do you have any other advice?

Comment: please up vote the comment if it helped you so that others can gain knowledge from it.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by deleting the provisioning profile that Xcode was auto generating from Apple's developer portal.  It appears that it was pulling it from there, and once I deleted it from there and archived and submitted it, it pulled the correct provisioning profile that I intended to use!

Comment: Thank you, I've been racking my head all day. This worked, but then you have to make sure to follow Jassi's idea above and "reload" the provisioning profiles.

Comment: Thank you! Deleting "XC: *" both from my Mac and Apple Developer Portal, followed with reloading profiles in Xcode preferences did fix the thing.

Comment: Apple is really not making this easy for the developers :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Xcode chose another provisioning profile, when you explicitly selected another.

If I were you I would find and delete the "XC: Rajib" provisioning profile and start over (restarting Xcode in the process).

I guess you *could* give Xcode the benefit of the doubt, by turning down the `Binary and Entitlements` triangle and carefully checking the entitlements then submitting if they're right... but I wouldn't feel good about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately when deleting the XC: Rajib provisioning profile Xcode auto-generated, it re-generates it again when I attempt to submit it after deleting it.  Any other advice?  I appreciate your help!

Comment: I hit a similar issue today and just spent the last couple of hours trying to get xcode to pick up the profile I wanted and hit the same auto regenerating problem.  In the end I gave up and submitted with the auto generated one as a part from the name the profiles were basically identical.  The submit and upload to the itunes seems to have worked fine.  btw you should be able to check the entitlements when xcode choose the profile on submit, or on the member center.